# R lang: Join two tables but replace colliding columns with data from a specified table

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Is there an existing way in standard R (or dplyr) of joining two tables/data.frames and with a condition on column collision?

Tried dplyr's joins already but they are limited by the matching column name requirement. I need to be able to join ANY two tables, regardless of their column names.

Here's some data and expected output:

```
> require(dplyr)
> data <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 11:13, c = 21:23, d = 101:103)
  a  b  c   d
1 1 11 21 101
2 2 12 22 102
3 3 13 23 103

REPLACE_LEFT_JOIN(select(data, a, b), select(data, c, d), collisionKeep = "right")
  a  b
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
REPLACE_LEFT_JOIN(select(data, a, b), mutate(select(data, a, c, d), a = a-1), collisionKeep = "right")
  a  b
1 0 11
2 1 12
3 2 13
REPLACE_FULL_JOIN(select(data, a, b), mutate(select(data, a, c, d), a = a-1), collisionKeep = "right")
  a  b  c   d
1 0 11 21 101
2 1 12 22 102
3 2 13 23 103
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these functions that DO work but I am feeling that I have reinvented the wheel + their logic isn't expandable to, say, left_join where you wanna keep colliding columns from the left table.

```
require(dplyr)
# Keeps everything from MINOR table but replaces colliding cols with MAJOR's cols.
replace_left_join <- function(data_minor, data_major) {
    c_sameMinor <- names(data_minor) %in% names(data_major)
    c_sameMajor <- names(data_major) %in% names(data_minor)
    data_merge <- data_minor
    data_merge[c_sameMinor] <- data_major[c_sameMajor][, names(data_merge[c_sameMinor])]
    data_merge
}
# Keeps everything from both tables but replaces colliding cols with MAJOR's cols.
replace_full_join <- function(data_minor, data_major) {
    c_sameMinor <- names(data_minor) %in% names(data_major)
    c_sameMajor <- names(data_major) %in% names(data_minor)
    data_merge <- data_minor
    data_merge[c_sameMinor] <- data_major[c_sameMajor][, names(data_merge[c_sameMinor])]
    bind_cols(data_merge, data_major[!c_sameMajor])
}
```